# How to do two rows of text on the x axis?

Tags: google-visualization, google-cdn, google-loader

I'm trying to do the graph you can see below. Check there are two rows of text on the x axis and I don't know how to do that with the Google API. How can I do this?

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Pretty sure you cant :(

Comment: @juvian is correct, you cannot add multiple lines of text like that.